# Find a specific column in an unknown table in a database?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to locate a specific column that is unknown in a database with 125 tables.  I am looking for a wildcard, say, "%watcher%".  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE column_name LIKE '%watcher%'
[AND table_schema = 'database']
```

Comment: I got an error when I ran this on the shell.

Perhaps I mistyped?

mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE column_name LIKE '%watcher%' [AND table_schema = 'database'];
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[AND table_schema = 'database']' at line 1

Comment: I've used square brackets to indicate that condition in them is optional. Either remove it altogether (e.g. everything after LIKE '%watcher%') or remove just the square bracket characters and replace "database" with your actual database name (keep single quotes)

Comment: I removed the square bracket and got another error: ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS' doesn't exist

Comment: What MySQL version are you using? It should work for 5.0 and above. If you're using 4.1 and below I'm afraid you're out of luck - the only way to show columns would be a "SHOW COLUMNS" statement which can only  run for one table at a time.

Comment: I am sorry don't know what I did wrong previously but this in fact does work.  Thank you for your patience with me!

Answer (score 1):

This shows you a bit more info...

```
DECLARE @columnName as varchar(100)
SET @columnName = 'ColumnName'

SELECT t.name AS Table, c.name AS Column,
ty.name AS Type, c.max_length AS Length, c.precision AS Precision
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
WHERE c.name LIKE @columnName
ORDER BY t.name, c.name
```

Hope it helps!