# In Oracle SQL how would you find a specific column entry(in an unknown table) in the database

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Suppose I'm using Oracle SQL and I want to find out which columns in the database have these values:

```
FIM
FIM
FIM
FNP
FJH
```

What I *do* know is that it was designed using the eBusiness suite(I think it was Oracle Reports). So I can use eTRM to narrow down.

But can I just use a stored procedure( like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818598/find-a-specific-column-entry-in-an-unknown-table-in-a-database) ) to find where the values are?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you have a couple of options.  Create a [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) index based off of your database and query against that OR you can use [Oracle Text](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/content.htm#sthref2643).  My personal recommendation is to use SOLR and remove excess load from your database, that of course is preference and YMMV.

Comment: Hmm, I don't believe I can do the SOLR( i don't have admin priv.) . so I will look at Oracle Text. thanks

Comment: @Adel you shouldn't need admin to run SOLR.  It comes with an embedded application server (Jetty) and you can at least prototype the work.